# .html not working with live() Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the method `live` and it initially works as intended, but the ajax 'success' callback is not functioning correctly on subsequent runs of the function.

```
$(function () {
    $('.vote').live('click', function () {
        url = '".base_url()."post/vote';
        post_id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'post_id=' + post_id,
            success: function (msg) {
                post = $('.num_vote' + post_id);
                vote = $('.votes' + post_id);
                $(vote).html(msg); // working only the first time
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You are using PHP in your Javascript file?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

Comment: Is vote a variable or a typo in your code in `$(vote).html(msg)`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of jQuery that you are using, you may need to use the **[.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** function as **[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

```
$(function(){
    $('.vote').on( 'click', function() {
            url = '".base_url()."post/vote';
            post_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'post_id=' + post_id,
                    success: function(msg) {                            
                        post = $('.num_vote' + post_id);
                        vote = $('.votes' + post_id);
                            $(vote).html(msg); // working only the first time

                    }
            });
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: If the function was working at all, then the error isn't due to the fact that OP used `live`. The method either exists or it doesn't, and if it exists OP is using an old jQuery version. Also, this usage of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) is for direct event handling, and is not equivalent to the delegated event handling which was being performed by `live`. You need to bind the handler to a parent element to handle delegated events, as shown in the docs.